# Trying to add mapviewballoons library in project

Tags: android-mapview

I am trying to add mapviewballoons library in my project, by right click project > properties > Android > isLibrary but whenever i click on Add button, in Project Selection box i am not getting any option to add library, i have downloaded mapviewballoons library in my downloads folder

Answer (score 0):

Hmm...I did it in few simple steps, If you have Git configured it will be easy just clone Git repository, right click->import project. If  mapviewballoons project is not checked as library (checkbox in properties->android is Library) then check it and simply in project in which you want to use balloons properties->android->add library and it will appear in list

Answer (score 0):

I dont have GIT, dont know what it is, nor have time to learn what that is.

Is there no easier way to import this stuff into a library project?
Why is Java always so ... hard!?

I dont want to spend days learning GIT, just to get those balloons!
My project is overtime already.